# calculate other fields using ko numeric extender

Tags: knockout.js

Please have a look at my code sample below-

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(0).extend({ numeric: 0 });
    this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(0).extend({ numeric: 0 });

    this.myNumberTwo = ko.computed(() => {
        return this.myNumberOne+1;
    });
    this.myNumberOne = ko.computed(() => {
        return this.myNumberTwo+1;
    });
}
```

My intent is to round off and set the value of Textbox1 when user inputs decimal number in Textbox2. PFB the example for better understanding of requirement-

1. If I enter 23.40 in Textbox1, then the value of Textbox 2 should set to 23
2. If I enter 1468.2489 in Textbox2, then the value of Textbox 1 should set to 1468

Right now it is not working as per the requirement above. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using the change **[`event`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)** binding:

On `change` of `Textbox 1`, update the `myNumberTwo` with the **[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** value of `myNumberOne`. And vice versa.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
  this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(0)
  this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(0)
  
  this.myNumberOneChanged = () => this.myNumberTwo(parseInt(this.myNumberOne()))
  this.myNumberTwochanged = () => this.myNumberOne(parseInt(this.myNumberTwo()))
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p><input data-bind="value: myNumberOne, event: { change: myNumberOneChanged }" /> Textbox 1</p>
<p><input data-bind="value: myNumberTwo, event: { change: myNumberTwochanged }" /> Textbox 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually subscribe to the observables to get the desired effect:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(0);
    this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(0);

    this.myNumberOne.subscribe((newVal) => this.myNumberTwo(Math.round(this.myNumberTwo())));
    this.myNumberTwo.subscribe((newVal) => this.myNumberOne(Math.round(this.myNumberOne())));
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/fbz2mvcy/